# After compiling a jsligo contract, the resulting michelson contract has errors and cannot be deployed

Tags: michelson, ligo

After compiling a jsligo contract, the resulting michelson contract has errors and cannot be deployed.
The error is "invalid primitive name".
Has anyone ever gotten this error ? Do you know where it might come from ?

I'm not sure, the whole view is underlined, so I'm guessing it's "get_balance".
But if I remove this view, it gives me the same error for the next view.

[image]